# Any way to connect wsdl file using .net core 2.0?

Tags: .net-core

I am using .net core 2.0 version ans then develop the application on same version  in my application have a some **wsdl** file how can i connect to the .net core

This is my Sample **Wsdl** File

http://www.holidaywebservice.com//HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx?wsdl

please Help Me...

Answer (score -1):

This should help you to get started.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide

From the link:

> In Solution Explorer, double-click the Connected Services node of the
>   project (for a .NET Core or .NET Standard project this option is
>   available when you right-click on the Dependencies node of the project
>   in Solution Explorer).
>
> On the Connected Services page, click Microsoft WCF Web Service
>   Reference Provider. This brings up the Configure WCF Web Service
>   Reference wizard:
>
> Select a service.
>
> There are several services search options available within the
>   Configure WCF Web Service Reference wizard:
>
> To search for services defined in the current solution, click the
>   Discover button. To search for services hosted at a specified address,
>   enter a service URL in the Address box and click the Go button. To
>   select a WSDL file that contains the web service metadata information,
>   click the Browse button. 3b. Select the service from the search
>   results list in the Services box. If needed, enter the namespace for
>   the generated code in the corresponding Namespace text box.
>
> Click the Next button to open the Data Type Options and the Client
>   Options pages. Alternatively, click the Finish button to use the
>   default options.